# Hiding empty array values in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a loop within PHP (codeigniter framework) that uses an array (`$products`) to display product data. Not all the products in the array have values.

Is there anyway that I can hide the call to display those values if they do not exist within the array.

Full code for the loop below;

```
<!-- Product item row -->    
    <?php foreach($products as $product): ?>  
    <div class="row product-list-row">
    <div class="col-md-2 item-img-container" align="center">
    <img class="img-responsive item-img" src="http://products.supercompare.co.uk<?= $product['logo']?>" alt="<?= $product['name']?> - supacompare.co.uk" width="190px" height="120px" /><br />
    <!--<a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#item-terms" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="item-terms">LESS DETAILS &#9660</a>-->
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-7 item-text">
    <h3><?= $product['name']?></h3>

    <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content-1">
    <p><strong><?= $product['custom_fields'][0]['field']?></strong>
    <br /><?= $product['custom_fields'][0]['value']?></p>
    </div>  
    <div class="content-2">
    <p><strong><?= $product['custom_fields'][1]['field']?></strong>
    <br /><?= $product['custom_fields'][1]['value']?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="content-3">
    <p><strong><?= $product['custom_fields'][2]['field']?></strong>
    <br /><?= $product['custom_fields'][2]['value']?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="content-4">
    <p><strong><?= $product['custom_fields'][3]['field']?></strong>
    <br /><?= $product['custom_fields'][3]['value']?></p>
    </div>
   <div class="content-bottom">
    <p><?= $product['footer_text']?></p>  
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-cta"><a class="apply-btn" href="<?= $product['tracking_link']?>" target="_blank">SEE DEAL &raquo;</a></div>

    <!--<div class="clearfix"></div>-->
    <!--<div id="item-terms" class="col-md-12 footer-terms" style="background-color:#B4B4B4; padding:10px; margin-top:10px;"><?= $product['footer_text']?></div>-->

    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: pls add printr($product); result

Comment: you can use `empty` or `isset` to check if the value is empty or the `key` is set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by checking the array for not empty by `!empty`.

```
if(!empty($product['custom_fields'][0]['value'])){
//your code
}
```

According to your code.

```
<?php if(!empty($product['custom_fields'][0]['value'])){ ?>
    <div class="content-1">
        <p><strong><?= $product['custom_fields'][0]['field']?></strong>
        <br /><?= $product['custom_fields'][0]['value']?></p>
    </div> 
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: All I am getting is an error when I try to add that code `<div class="content-1">
    <p><strong><?php if(!empty($product['custom_fields'][0]['value']) ['custom_fields'][0]['field']?></strong>
    <br /><?= $product['custom_fields'][0]['value']?></p>
    </div> `

Comment: I am using the updated answer thanks. I get this error - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'  - could it be because I'm using it within a foreach statement?

Comment: Glad to know that.. Welcome

Answer (score 0):

here is an example :

```
<?php
if(isset($product['custom_fields'][0]['value']) && $product['custom_fields'][0]['value'] !=""){
//your code
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    foreach ($product['custom_fields'] as $value) {
        if (!$value) {
            continue 2;
        }
    }
    //your code here!!!
}
```